# How can I view the most recently created Google documents in my Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

How can I view the most recently created Google documents in my Google Drive? I access my Google Drive via a web browser.

https://drive.google.com/drive/recent sorts files by date of modification, not creation.

Answer (score 3):

That can be done from the side panel in Google Drive.

Select `Recent` and the files will be listed accordingly.

[image]

However, that will list all your files. I'm not certain that you can filter further to just include Docs (or other types) other than by using the search tools at the top `Search in Drive` and entering *Docs* and using the icon at the end of the search bar  to show search options and making your selections there.

Answer (score 1):

Reddit user [andmalc](https://www.reddit.com/user/andmalc) proposed this [search query](https://www.reddit.com/r/googledocs/comments/10d1j6d/how_can_i_view_the_google_documents_i_most/j4nhi9g/) that specifies a using a created date range::

```
createdafter:2023-01-05 and createdbefore:2023-01-15
```